# What is "automatic stack expansion"?

Tags: linux, process, memory, limit

[getrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) has the following definition
in the man pages:

**RLIMIT_AS**
The maximum size of the process's virtual memory (address space) in bytes. This limit affects calls to brk(2), mmap(2) and mremap(2), which fail with the error ENOMEM upon exceeding this limit. Also ***automatic stack expansion*** will fail (and generate a SIGSEGV that kills the process if no alternate stack has been made available via sigaltstack(2)).  Since the value is a long, on machines with a 32-bit long either this limit is at most 2 GiB, or this resource is unlimited.

What is meant by "automatic stack expansion" here? Does the stack in a Linux/UNIX environment grow as needed? If yes, what's the exact mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes stacks grow dynamically. The stack is in the top of the memory growing downwards towards the heap.

```
--------------
| Stack      |
--------------
| Free memory|
--------------
| Heap       |
--------------
     .
     .
```

The heap grows upwards (whenever you do malloc) and the stack grows downwards as and when new functions are called. The heap is present just above the BSS section of the program. Which means the size of your program and the way it allcates memory in heap also affect the maximum stack size for that process. Usually the stack size is unlimited (till heap and stack areas meet and/or overwrite which will give a stack overflow and SIGSEGV :-)

This is only for the user processes, The kernel stack is fixed always (usually 8KB)

Comment: "Usually the stack size is unlimited", no, usually it limited by 8Mb (`ulimit -s`).

Comment: yes you are right in most systems. You are checking the shell's ulimit command, if so there is a hard limit on the stack size, which is unlimited (ulimit -Hs). Anyway, that point was to stress that stack and heap grows in the opposite directions.

Comment: Then how is "automatic expansion" is any different from "pushing elements to the stack"? From your explanation, I get the feeling that they are the same.

Also, I felt like starting points of stack and heap are way more than 8MB, so the stack can grow as much as it need (or it hits the heap). Is that true? If yes, how does the operating system decided on where to place the heap and the stack?

Comment: They are the same, but stacks dont have a fixed size unless you hard limit the size using rlimit. Stack is placed at the end of the virtual memory area, and heap is immediatly af*er tke data segment of the executable.

Comment: I understand, thanks. However, I don't think I get the "stacks don't have fixed size" part. If that's the case, what's the 8Mb soft limit for?

Comment: hard limits and soft limits are for managing user quota, it is not strictly the limit of the kernel and the memory. Limits are purely for administration.

Comment: I guess this textbook explanation is hardly relevant nowdays. For instance, how does the MMU fits in this model?

Comment: @lvella Actually yes the model presented here only works if you have MMU. Otherwise how would all processes use the same addresses without conflicting each others ?

Answer (score 8):

The exact mechanism is given here, on Linux: in [handling a page fault on anonymous mappings](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L3714) you [check to see whether it's a "grown does allocation"](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arc/mm/fault.c#L101) that you should expand like a stack. If the VM area record says you should, then you adjust the start address to expand the stack.

When a page fault occurs, depending on the address, it may be serviced (and the fault quashed) via stack expansion. This "growing downwards on a fault" behavior for virtual memory can be requested by arbitrary user programs with the `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flag being passed to the `mmap` syscall.

You can mess around with this mechanism in a user program as well:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
        long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
        void *mem = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_GROWSDOWN|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        if (MAP_FAILED == mem) {
                perror("failed to create growsdown mapping");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        volatile char *tos = (char *) mem + page_size;

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < 10 * page_size; ++i)
                tos[-i] = 42;

        fprintf(stderr, "inspect mappping for originally page-sized %p in /proc... press any key to continue...\n", mem);
        (void) getchar();

        if (munmap(mem, page_size))
                perror("failed munmap");

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When it prompts you find the pid of the program (via `ps`) and look at `/proc/$THAT_PID/maps` to see how the original area has grown.

Comment: Is it ok to call munmap for the original mem and page_size even if the memory region has grown via MAP_GROWSDOWN? I presume yes, because otherwise it would be a very complex API to use, but the documentation does not say anything explicitly on this matter

Comment: MAP_GROWSDOWN shouldn't be used, and has been removed from glibc (see https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/ for why).